# How to avoid "Can't set headers after they are sent" when cancelling a save file prompt

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I have a page with file uploading/downloading functionality. 
When I try to download a file **AND** cancel the save file prompt, which happens after the `res.writeHead` part, it leaves the headers and it waits for the `res.write` and `res.end` parts.

The problem is that these are escaped if the prompt is cancelled, making every other response fail with the error "Can't set headers after they are sent".

Is there anyway to end the response catching the cancelled prompt event is some way, or any other way to avoid this?

The part that sets headers and streams data for the file download (*located in a function that is called in the* `/download/:filename` *route*) is :

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'});
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
        filename: files[0].filename
    });

    readstream.on('data', function(data){
        res.write(data);
    });

    readstream.on('end', function(){
        res.end();
    });
```

If this sequence is not completed, every other response fails.

example:

`res.status(403).send('You have no access to this file');`

in another controller, called in the same page.
(*I guess if I redirected to another page headers would actually get cleared?*)

*If I select download location and press ok, no error occurs

*I am not having a double response in a loop, to avoid this common mistake answer :)

Comment: are you using a global res object? pls show us some code

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Thanks for the answers, updated with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in express you can check for `res.headersSent`, this way you would be able to avoid the exception

```
if(res.headersSent){
  return;
} else {
  //set you headers
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Didn't know there is a check for this. Still I don't seem to find any method to delete these headers in the API :/

Comment: try `res.set(headerName, null)`

Comment: the problem was fixed.. for some reason I had a query to mongo return more than 1 file when I was expecting only 1 for response. Thanks a lot anyway :)